# Sum formula DAX

Tags: powerbi

Good evening, I was trying to do some analysis on this dataset.
In the first dashboard I was making a graph but unfortunately it doesn't work on as it should. The histogram should not have equal bars, what did I do wrong?
Is it a problem in the links or do you need a formula in DAX?
Thanks!

(in the file Tot is not a number but also if I change it the problem is the same)

The 2 and the 3 must be similar but they aren't

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 problems.

1. In your top chart, you're trying to go from INT[Cantiere] to COST[Tot]

Your relationships are uni-directional and therefore do not flow that way.

[image]

2. You are using implicit instead of hand-written, explicit measures. Using explicit measures gives you more control.

I can't advise how to fix as I don't understand your model but this is the crux of the problem.